# remove substring from string using python

Tags: python

I would like to remove 2 last sub-strings from a string like the following example :

```py
str="Dev.TTT.roker.{i}.ridge.{i}."

str1="Dev.TTT.roker.{i}.ridge.{i}.obj."
```

if in the last two strings between the dot `.` there is  a `{i}` we have to remove it as well.
so the result of python script should be loke this :

the expected result for str is : `Dev.TTT.`

the expected result for str1 is : `Dev.TTT.roker.{i}.`

Comment: what have you tried so far? You stuck anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can simply split by `.` and ignore empty string or `{i}`.
- Also do not use keyword as variable. In your case dont use `str` as variable name.

```py
def solve(s):
    x = s.split('.')
    cnt = 2
    l = len(x) - 1
    while cnt and l:
        if x[l] == '' or x[l] == '{i}':
            l -= 1
            continue
        else:
            cnt -= 1
            l -= 1
    return '.'.join(x[:l+1]) + '.'

str1="Dev.TTT.roker.{i}.ridge.{i}."

str2="Dev.TTT.roker.{i}.ridge.{i}.obj."

print(solve(str1))
print(solve(str2))
```

output:

```
Dev.TTT.
Dev.TTT.roker.{i}.
```